# How to build a CNN to correctly classify the edges of a quadrilateral?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, deeplearning4j

I am trying to implement a CNN to correctly detect the edges of a quadrilateral 
in a **322x322** binary image i.e. a white quadrilateral on a black background image e.g.

[image]

the network output is designed to represent x and y sandwiched together so for any given
image from the dataset, four(`4`) corresponding x and y neuron pairs should be fired/excited so that
my labels for the training is a one-hot-label encoding(multi-class classification) for each xy pair of edges for the quardilateral
e.g.say my image is 10x10 if the first quad has the following edges(**x,y**) where possible (x,y)-values are from [**0-9**] 
 => (`1`,`2`) (`3`,`8`) (`4`,`3`) (`5`,`7`)
my label is like

[image][[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bq6Uk.png)

for each quad. Here is the configuration for my network in java using deeplearning4j.

```
         MultiLayerConfiguration EDGE_PERCEPTRON = new NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder()
                    .seed(seed)
                    .l2(0.0005)
                    .weightInit(WeightInit.XAVIER)
                    .updater(new Nesterovs(new MapSchedule(ScheduleType.ITERATION, lrSchedule)))
                    .list()
                    .layer(0, new ConvolutionLayer.Builder(8, 8)
                            .stride(2, 2)
                            .padding(0, 0)
                            .nIn(channels)
                            .nOut(filtersize10)
                            .activation(Activation.IDENTITY)
                            .build())
                    .layer(1, new ConvolutionLayer.Builder(4, 4)
                            .stride(2, 2)
                            .padding(0, 0)
                            .nOut(filtersize20)
                            .activation(Activation.IDENTITY)
                            .build())
                    .layer(2, new SubsamplingLayer.Builder(SubsamplingLayer.PoolingType.MAX)
                            .kernelSize(2, 2)
                            .stride(1, 1)
                            .padding(0, 0)
                            .build())
                    .layer(3, new DenseLayer.Builder().activation(Activation.SIGMOID)
                            .nOut(outputSize).build())
                    .layer(4, new OutputLayer.Builder(LossFunctions.LossFunction.XENT)
                            .nOut(outputSize)
                            .activation(Activation.SIGMOID)
                            .build())
                    .setInputType(InputType.convolutionalFlat(height, width, channels))
                    .backprop(true).pretrain(false).build();
```

Here is it's graphical representation

[image]

Is there anything wrong with my configuration or rather what do you think I am doing wrong. The network doesn't learn anything from the dataset, the predictions  are all uniform and all lesser than 0.1 .
How can I configure the network correctly to give the right predictions?

Comment: This '...sir' (x2) you are using, especially since you have never used it before in your comments, can be easily interpreted as *mocking*, which is never a good idea here...

Comment: Woah! can't believe you really went as far looking up my previous interactions. really sorry if you took offense it wasn't intended to sound... I could delete the comment or If you would like me to delete the question(I can probably repost later). It's a lingo thing here. didn't mean to sound however it may seem to you. I bet you 've looked me up on Google already. apologies man. didn't mean to disrespect you in any way

Comment: Everything good, and no worries at all...